# How to export and import bucket from one couchbase server to another

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to export the bucket from one couchbase server(10.x.x.x) -- it gets success, but while I am trying to import the exported bucket in another couchbase server(20.x.x.x.), it shows **Attention - Failed to reach erlang port mapper. Could not connect to "20.x.x.x" on port "4369". This could be due to an incorrect host/port combination or a firewall in place between the servers.**

If any one knows how to transfer one bucket from one couchbase server to another.Please let me know.

Comment: @jdebon: You can remove it yourself (or at least suggest an edit)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going for the silly question: Have you checked port `4369` is exposed on both machines? Couchbase instances use this port to communicate with each other (see [Couchbase ports documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/install-ports.html)).

To check the port is exposed, try `telnet 20.x.x.x 4369`

Also, please provide the command you use to import. From which machine do you import? By REST API or CBQ?